# With unsigned commits by multiple devs, how to merge with main branch?

Tags: github, gnupg

We have a new branch, say `feature-x`, which has multiple commits by multiple devs, all unsigned. This branch has merging blocked with the `main` branch since "The base branch requires all commits to be signed" - how do we merge it?

The command-line instructions won't work, since pushing to main requires at least one review, so we can't push to `main` directly after locally merging.
If we were to sign all commits in the `feature-x` branch, how to go about it? Can a single dev sign the commits from all the devs, following the suggestions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/397149/can-you-gpg-sign-old-commits)?

EDIT: (additional)
On attempting the CLI instructions given, I get this error:

```
remote: error: GH006: Protected branch update failed for refs/heads/main.
remote: error: At least 1 approving review is required by reviewers with write access.
```

I suppose if I create a new branch from this main locally, (some more steps) and raise a PR from a new branch, it would still have the issue due to the unsigned commits from different devs - since the new branch would be identical to the `feature-x` in its current state.

Also, visual state of the PR on GitHub:
[image]

EDIT #2: It's not a solution but we turned off the branch protection rule and merged it in now. Perhaps this was the case with earlier PRs - it might have been flipped on right before this PR

Comment: Have you tried doing the review from the UI?

Comment: `feature-x` is reviewed - the issue in merging it is the unsigned-ness, and `main`, from what I understand, to do a PR, I need both branches to be on GitHub - but here I have a local main (after following CLI instructions) and a remote main, so I think I can't raise a PR and hence a review. I will edit the question to clarify this, sorry

Comment: I do not mean the concept of **review** in a casual manner. I mean that you have a way to add a reviewer on the left-hand side of the page when you work with a PR and then the reviewer can approve the PR. Have you done that?

Comment: Yes, that is the review I meant - the PR is reviewed (approved) by all reviewers (on behalf of the code owner)

Comment: Interesting. Was it assigned to someone? Was it accepted?

Comment: This isn't a Git issue per se, it's strictly a GitHub one: protected branches don't exist in Git, only in GitHub (and practically every other commercial hosting site, but each one does it a little differently...). You'll need to read the GitHub documentation on this, or get a GitHub-specific answer; I trimmed the tags down a bit to try to get the more-specific answer.

Comment: @LajosArpad no, nobody was assigned. However we've previously had a PR with reviews approved, unsigned commits and no assignees - it merged just fine (it was 17 days ago, perhaps some feature on GitHub was changed regarding signing?)

Comment: @VedaantArya I do not know either, I would answer if I knew the answer. I'm only thinking about it together with you. I wonder: would assigning the PR to someone and then that person validating it somehow or even merging it solve your problem? There's one way to find out.

Comment: @LajosArpad Thanks for trying to help out :D, for now we've disabled the signing branch protection rule - and the PR could be merged - I'll try out the assignment trick in a personal project, will update here as soon as I get the time

Comment: Excellent. If you try that out and it works, then you can write an answer to your question, or let me know here in the comment section and I will write an answer myself.